# MySQL record is not inserting with the current query format

Tags: mysql

My database is account_info, and I've created the following table as 'master':

```
  `AccountID` BIGINT(12) NOT NULL,
  `AccountName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Application_Description` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `Environment` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `IGW` boolean NULL,
  `Backend_Access` boolean NULL,
  `Confidential_Data` boolean NULL,
  `IP_Range` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Account_DL` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `TeamOps_DL` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `AD_Group` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `TeamDL_ADGroupOwner` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `AccountKeys` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `KeyARNs` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `AWS_Services` VARCHAR(200) NULL,
  `ArchitectureLink` VARCHAR(300) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`AccountID`, `AccountName`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `Unique_Keys` (`AccountKeys` ASC, `KeyARNs` ASC) INVISIBLE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `Account` (`AccountID` ASC, `AccountName` ASC) INVISIBLE);
```

I'm trying to insert a record, and it's not working:

```
insert into account_info.master values
(123456789876, 'test', 'test1', test2', TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'aKJSLKJDFL', 'ashdfjalskjflh', 'akshdkfhkdhfksdhfk', 'asdfsfsfsfdsf');
```

I've tried substituting 1 for true and 0 for false (since mysql changed my boolean data type to tinyint), and I've also substituted NULL for ' ', but it's still not inserting. Can someone let me know what I need to change?

P.S. I do realize that since I'm in the database, I don't need to include account_info within the query, but I'm writing it this way in case we end up storing various tables across databases.

Comment: You have a missing single quote before string « test2 ». Is it a typo ?

Comment: What does *it’s not working* mean ? Are you getting an error, which one ?

Comment: what error you are getting. please post the error

Comment: Yes, that was a typo in the above! That wasn't the issue in my query, though. Even with the single quote inserted, here is the error I am getting:
ERROR 1416 (22003): Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the Null in your table structure so you cant insert empty value ' ' instead of NULL

```
insert into account_info.master values
(123456789876, 'test', 'test1', test2', TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'aKJSLKJDFL', 'ashdfjalskjflh', 'akshdkfhkdhfksdhfk', 'asdfsfsfsfdsf');
```

Comment: Well, I tried that (noted in the original comment - I actually started with Null). Here are the results from that: 
mysql> insert into account_info.master values (123456789876, 'test', 'test1', 'test2', TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'aKJSLKJDFL', 'ashdfjalskjflh', 'akshdkfhkdhfksdhfk', 'asdfsfsfsfdsf');
ERROR 1416 (22003): Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field
mysql>

Comment: Ah, it worked this time! I believe there was a server issue. Thank you for the insights!